# Description of jwst data acquisition pipeline

Tags: james-webb-telescope

I am attempting to try to obtain some proficiency in reviewing and analyzing JWST data.  Toward that end, I have installed python language jdaviz environment and files and JWST python environment and files.  I am tinkering with some of the apps and example data.  I realize there are months before any real data is obtained but I'd like to develop some proficiency during the shakedown period.

I wish to find a description of the final operational data acquisition pipeline for JWST. There are descriptions of a calibration reference (CRDS) data pipeline but I don't know if that is only for initial calibration or is that for the final data flow.

Could someone point me to the final data pipeline scheme and needed software as well as to how that is arrived at from the initial efforts at startup and calibration.

I need some technical detail; not layman level; but I am also not an analytical astronomer either; just a broken-down engineer.

Comment: I was thinking same thing.  But I saw more jwst items here than on astronomy exchange.  Is there a simple way to move this thread to astronomy?  Or else, I'll just start a new one there.

Comment: The best/right way to migrate is to close as off-topic and then either wait for a moderator to decide to migrate to Astronomy, or after you also vote to close for you to flag for moderator assistance in migration. It's a great question and I am pretty sure the moderators in Astronomy SE will decide to accept the migration request. We try to avoid re-posting the same question in two places, even if one is deleted (since it can be undeleted later) because cross-posting can lead to answer fragmentation. I've started the closing process now.

Comment: What is the process to migrate to another forum.  I couldn't find how to do that so I reposted it into astronomy.  Sorry to generate confusion.  How do I request moderator assistance?

Comment: My comment directly above yours explains the process to migrate. To reach a moderator, look under your post, click "flag" and then "something else" from the options. The mods are nice, just say you need assistance: you've got two copies now, you want to keep the one in Astronomy but you can't delete this one because it already has an answer.

Comment: Don't worry, Stack Exchange takes a while to get used to. It's not really a forum, it's a rigid question and answer site with the goal of having an encyclopedic body of answer for future readers to enjoy, with the "side benefit" of the question authors also getting answers. *Have fun!*

Comment: I've asked the current answer author to consider deleting their answer here and moving it to the copy of this question in Astronomy SE. Once that's done, you'll be able to delete this copy so that it is no longer cross-posted and receiving answers on two different sites at the same time.